# What does this flag mean? How is it related to Raoh?

Tags: hokuto-no-ken-legends-of-dark-king

We see this flag/banner raised several times throughout the series.  It looks like a snake with wings and 3 pairs of legs.  It's our protagonist's (Raoh, the Dark King) flag.

What does it mean?  How is it related to Raoh and/or the school of the North Star?

[image]